# jQuery: Pass variable to :eq() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to find out why the following lines of code do not work:

```
$('#add-cloud > select').change(function() {
    var selected = parseInt($('#add-cloud select option:selected').val()); 
    $("#cloud-calculator table tr:eq(selected)").css("color", "red");
});
```

If I change `:eq(selected)` to `:eq(4)` for example - works fine. How do you pass variable as an argument to `:eq()` ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to concatenate your variable with your selector:

```
$("tr:eq("+selected+")");
```

Comment: The code is right, but the description of what's going on with it is very wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it it single quotes before and it didn't work. I guess I wasn't paying attention to the double quotes.

Comment: Right, single quotes didn't work because what you're doing isn't 'escaping' anything, it's terminating the first string "tr:eq(", adding the selected variable, and then adding another string ")".

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean "escape" in that sense. Concatenate would be less misleading.

Answer (score 4):

The way you're doing it, you're embedding the actual string `"selected"` in the selector.  You need to construct a string using your `selected` variable as a part of it:

```
$("#cloud-calculator table tr:eq(" + selected + ")").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can simply use the 'this' object to get the seleted value.

```
$('#add-cloud > select').change(function() 
{
    var rowSelector = '#cloud-calculator table tr:eq(' + parseInt(this.val()) + ')';
    $(rowSelector).css("color", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can pass variable to `eq() function`. But you need to disable **Firebug**. Otherwise it wont work.

Please check this example.

```
var index = 3       
$('#sidebar_menu li:eq('+index+')').css({"color":"#050959"});
```