# Does :eq() slector in jquery take string variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been reading this question:

[jQuery: Pass variable to :eq() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074728/jquery-pass-variable-to-eq-does-not-work)

Usually when we use `:eq(4)` we pass a variable of type number to `eq` selector. But when we do `:eq("+selected+")` we are passing a string to the `:eq` selector.

So my question is, does :eq() selector in jquery take string variables or number variables?

Comment: you use is() for selector/pseudoselector

Comment: @madalinivascu I am using it for indexes.

Comment: @user31782 is this what you mean [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/c0fd2724/)

Comment: any number adding to string becomes string.

Comment: > *:eq(4) we pass a variable of type number to eq selector*: 4 is not a variable it's a number /constant

Comment: @madalinivascu I mean 4's type is still number.

Comment: @guradio console doesn't work in my browser. Here is what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/c0fd2724/1/

Answer (score 0):

For this question(or any other jquery selector question) i suggest you consult the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) where you can see that `eq()` accepts only integers

`:eq("+selected+")` is a selector not a function see [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: I saw the jquery documentation before asking the question. I still don't understand how  :eq() selector in jquery take string variables.

Comment: a selector is a string that is parsed by jquery to find the element described by it

Comment: How does jquery parse the `:eq()` selector internally?

Comment: from i can tell it uses regex

Comment: When we use `:eq(4)`. Does jquery convert `4` into a string?

Comment: no because `:eq(4)` is already a string jquery uses regex to get that string 4 it turn it in a integer and than runes the `.eq()` function